# Convert epoch to Date

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, epoch

I want to get Today's date in epoch or milisecs, but with the time part set to start of today i.e. 24:00(midnight)

For example

At the moment time is **10-APR-2013 17:56:44.455** which in

```
mili-seconds is 1365613004461
epoch = 1365613004
```

Can some one please tell me how to get epoch for 10-APR-2013 24:00:00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the time to 0:00:00 like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss.S").format(cal.getTime()));

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss.S").format(cal.getTime()));
```

The first value prints as `10-04-13 18:10:40.832` and the second `10-04-13 00:00:00.0`.

Comment: You'll want to set the `Calendar`'s (and `SimpleDateFormat`'s) `TimeZone` to `"UTC"` before doing these manipulations, or your result will be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

#### Start of a day

The JSR-310 implementation, also known as `java.time` or the modern date-time API provides us with two ways to get the start of a day:

1. [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--): Combines a date with the time of midnight to create a `LocalDateTime` at the start of this date.
2. [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-): Returns a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) from this date at the earliest valid time according to the rules in the time-zone.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start date-time of the day in the system's time zone
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Start date-time of the day in a given time zone
        ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.now(tz).atStartOfDay(tz);
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay());
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2024-02-23T00:00
2024-02-23T00:00
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/o5e9rC)

#### Coming back to your problem:

Let's first discuss a problem in your question:

> At the moment time is 10-APR-2013 17:56:44.455 which in
>
> `mili-seconds is 1365613004461`
>
> `epoch = 1365613004`

The milli-seconds you have got  is off by 6 milliseconds. Let's see how:

```
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long yourValue = 1365613004461L;
        long correctValue = LocalDateTime.of(2013, Month.APRIL, 10, 17, 56, 44, 455000000)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
                .toInstant()
                .toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(correctValue);
        System.out.println(yourValue - correctValue);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1365613004455
6
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/crIodt)

#### Finally, the value you are looking for:

Now that you have understood the nuts and bolts, let's find the value you are looking for:

```
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
        Instant instant = LocalDate.now(tz)
                .atStartOfDay(tz)
                .toInstant();

        long epochMillis = instant.toEpochMilli();
        long epochSeconds = instant.getEpochSecond();
        System.out.println(epochMillis);
        System.out.println(epochSeconds);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
1708646400000
1708646400
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/UwjFED)

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working on an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>